# PatternValidator directive doesn't validate when the correct regex string value is passed to it

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-forms, angular4-forms, angular-template-form

I have an input field whose input should be a positive number.

```
    <input  type="number" [(ngModel)]='assetValue'
     type="number" pattern="positiveNumberRegex">
```

`positiveNumber()` returns a RegExp. I store it's string value in a variable. This is done in the OnInit Life cycle hook.

```
this.positiveNumberRegex = this.regexPatternService.positiveNumber().source;
console.log(this.positiveNumberRegex); // ^[1-9][0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$
```

But the validation fails when I enter a positive number.

If I hardcode the regex to the pattern directive, it works fine.

```
    <input  type="number" [(ngModel)]='assetValue'
     type="number" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*$">
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

use the `[]` around pattern to support the binding.

```
 [pattern]="positiveNumberRegex">
```

Comment: Thank you  It worked!

But why did it work with the hardcoded value earlier?

Answer (score 0):

[pattern] brackets tell angular to read whats in the expression positiveNumberRegex, without the brackets it treats it as a regular string